# How to fetch data in textboxes from datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, datatables

My JSON data looks like this and I am trying to get it sent through datatables.

JSON data:

```
{
  "data": [{
    "name": "name1",
    "value": "value1",
    "list": [{
      "sname": "sname1",
      "svalue": "svalue1"
    }, {
      "sname": "sname2",
      "svalue": "svalue2"
    }]
  }]
}
```

JQuery Code:

```
var pk =   $("#pk").val();                                                               
console.log(pk);
url="/register/search?id="+pk;
console.log(url);   
$('#largeTable').DataTable({
  "ajax" : url,   
  "bDestroy":true,
  "columns":[
    {"data": "name"},
    {"data": "value"},
    {"data": "list.sname"},
    {"data": "list.svalue"},
    {"data": null,"defaultContent":editview}
  ]
});
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="box-body">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="largeTable" style="background-color: white;"  >
    <thead  style="background-color:#CCE5FF">
      <tr>
        <th>EName</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>SuperiorName</th>                     
        <th>SValue</th>
        <th>action</th> 
      </tr>                    
    </thead>
  </table>            
</div>
```

i want fetch Datatable values in below html page textboes.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="RegistrationForm" >
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group ">
      <label for="ename" class="col-md-4 control-label">EName</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">                                  
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ename"  name="ename" placeholder="EName" />
      </div>
    </div>                     
    <div class="form-group ">
      <label for="value" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Value</label>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="value" placeholder="value"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group ">
      <label for="sname" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Supr.Name</label>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sname"  name = "sname" placeholder="Supr.Name"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group ">
      <label for="svalue" class="col-lg-4 control-label">SValue</label>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="svalue"  name="svalue"  placeholder="SValue"/>
      </div>
    </div> </div>                                                                                    
</form>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do, but it's probably much wiser to use the raw JSON data for this, rather than trying to get stuff out of the datatable. As it stands, though, this seems like little more than a coding request, which is off topic on Stack Overflow. Have you considered looking for a datatables plugin that supports inline editing? Could make for a much more convenient experience for you *and* your users.

Comment: In which scenario you want to populate data into the form ?

Comment: @Samuel J Mathew: i have a editview button. when i click that button one page displaying. please see my updated code

Comment: i got solution by using thymeleaf

Comment: @user7646838: if you can expand on that answer, and you feel it would be useful for future readers, please add it below.

Comment: @halfer: okay sure. you know how to iterate my above json data?

Comment: Presumably you know how to, since you have solved it ("using Thymeleaf")?

Comment: @user7646838 can you pls share the link (Thymeleaf) of the code you are facing issue so that i may help you

Comment: I have removed ASAP begging from three of your recent questions. The community sadly has had to [discuss this kind of approach](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) to volunteers, and universally finds it unacceptable. Please do not add hurrying messages of any kind to your questions.

Comment: @halfer: okay thank you